# Match two strings with the same word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, match

Given two strings, how can I do something if both strings have one word in common?

For example: `"foo bar"` and `"foo line"` both have the word `"foo"`. The strings could be 3 words long or more, like `"foo bar"` and `"blue foo line"`.

What I've tried so far:

```
var m = "foo bar";
var n = "foo line";
if(m.match(/n/g)){
  alert("match");
}
```

Comment: Am confuse about what you asking.

Comment: What other conditions apply? For example, should the algorithm be case sensitive? Should it only match if **one** (and no more than one) word  is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/iwalam/3/edit

better version :

```
var m = "foo bar".split(' ');

var n = "foo line".split(' ');
var isOk=0;

    for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
    {
    for (var j=0;j<n.length;j++)

    {
      var reg = new RegExp("^"+m[i]+"$", "gi");

    if (n[j].match(reg) )
    {isOk=1;break;}
    }
    }

if (isOk==1)
  alert("match");
```

Comment: many thanks. one problem, `var m = " bar".split(' ');`, `var n = "foo line".split(' ');`, also matched. notice the **space**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more explicit version, without the unneeded regular expression:

```
function hasWordMatch(a, b, case_sensitive) {
    if (case_sensitive !== true) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
    }
    var a_parts = a.split(' ');
    var b_parts = b.split(' ');
    var a_length = a_parts.length;
    var b_length = b_parts.length;
    var i_a, i_b;

    for (i_a = 0; i_a < a_length; i_a += 1) {
        for (i_b = 0; i_b < b_length; i_b += 1) {
            if (a_parts[i_a] === b_parts[i_b]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(hasWordMatch("foo bar", "foo baz")); // true
console.log(hasWordMatch("foo bar", "bada bing")); // false
console.log(hasWordMatch("FOO BAR", "foo baz")); // true
console.log(hasWordMatch("FOO BAR", "foo baz", true)); // false
```

The regex in your question is case sensitive, but this version is case insensitive by default. You can make is case sensitive by passing `true` as the third argument.

It's also up on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WQBSv/