# How can I use the .search() method more efficiently in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, search

I am currently using the Javascript Search() method to search for a match in a string. 
I want to find the closest match, for example, if the string is 'apple iphone', and a person searches 'iphone 6' I want there to be a match, but for some reason, the .search method doesn't work this way.

Is there a more efficient way to use this or another method that can be more useful?

```
const test = "apple iphone"
// this doesn't return -1 indicating there was a match
console.log(test.search('iphone'))

// this returns -1 indicating there wasn't any match at all despite there 
// being the word "iphone" in there 
console.log(test.search('iphone 5'))
```

Comment: try using elastic search. It will return what you need with a relevance score as well

Comment: Instead of search you can use `.match()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Also, if you don't care about the exact similarity and you just need to find any similar part you can use `.split` function. So your string will be split by space indicator and then you can use `indexOf` once for `iphone 5`, next time for `iphone` and lastly for `5`

Comment: @Pedrammarandi when using .match it behaves the same as the search method did in my example above, it returns null if trying to .match() "iphone 7" against the string "apple iphone"

Comment: @Pedrammarandi Can you answer the question with an example of your solution using the split function then the indexOf ?

Comment: The approach of @stdob-- is nice, it's like what I said. But something is missed in his approach, you have to check is there any `iphone 5` or nuh then you would execute the reduce function.

Comment: @Pedrammarandi you're right just took a look! Thanks

Comment: @john-raymon I've edited my last comment

Comment: You can also use `test.search(term.split(/\s/).join('|'))`.

Comment: @HassanImam Your answer was super simple and exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @john-raymon Glad to help you man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below sample code.

```js
const test = 'apple iphone'

const term = 'iphone 5'

// Split by whitespace
const terms = term.split(/\s/)

// Test all sub term
const result = terms.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  if (test.search(currentValue) > -1) previousValue.push(currentValue)
  return previousValue
}, [])

console.log(result.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Match two strings with the same word in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614169/match-two-strings-with-the-same-word-in-javascript][1])

From the answer above , I think the flowing code is what you are looking for :

```
<script>
 var m = "apple iphone".split(' ');
   var n = "iphone 6".split(' ');
      var isOk=0;

    for (var i=0;i<m.length;i++)
 {
    for (var j=0;j<n.length;j++)

 {
    var reg = new RegExp("^"+m[i]+"$", "gi");

  if (n[j].match(reg) )
   {isOk=1;break;}
          }
        }

     if (isOk==1)
       alert("match");

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean searching something 'apple' **OR** 'iphone', use it as condition.

```
'iphone'.search(/apple|iphone/);    //this doesn't return -1
'iphone 5'.search(/apple|iphone/);   //this doesn't return -1
```